# General Fredholm alternative

Tags: functional-analysis

came across this exercise in a book and I wasn't able to solve it.

> **Exercise**:
>
> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T\in K(X,X)$ (the set of compact operators from $X$ to $X$). Show that operator $A=I-T$ satisfies
>
> $\DeclareMathOperator{\codim}{codim}\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}\dim\ker A=\dim\ker A^*=\codim\Im A=\codim\Im A^*$

I started like this: assume $x\in\ker A$. Then $Ix-Tx=0\Longrightarrow Tx=Ix\Longrightarrow Tx=x$. Now apply any $f\in X^*$ to both sides to get $f(Tx)=f(x)$. By definition of adjoint operator $f(Tx)=(T^*f)(x)$, so we get $(T^*f)(x)=f(x)$. But this holds for any $f\in X^*$, so $T^*f=f\Longrightarrow T^*f=I^*f\Longrightarrow A^*f=0$ on $x\in \ker A$. Hence we get the first equality $\dim\ker A=\dim\ker A^*$. Is this even correct? How would I proceed to get the rest?